# Why has Texstudio changed my font?

Tags: fonts

As you can see from the screenshot, my font has changed and I'm not sure why. It looks like a variant of the default font. Attached is a screenshot and excerpt of my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Coordinate Systems \& Associated Calculus}
  \section{Core Elements}
  \subsection{Key functions and Definitions}
\end{document}
```

[image: What it looks like:]

Comment: the posted code produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pITsD.png) If you do not et that please show the log file that you get from running this test file